# Display error when turning on the system Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have played a little with xrandr and now whenever I turn on the system, a message pops off in the screenshot below.

I want it back to the default settings and remove this annoying error message.

[image]

Edit: Here is what the `/etc/profile` looks like:

```
if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Comment: it would be helpful to edit your question and add the respective line that you added to `/etc/profile`

Comment: I really do not remember what a particular line I have added. I added the whole file. Sorry for the lack of clarification.

Comment: Okay, so it seems the relevant line is in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or in one of the `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` files.